# LaTeX3: token list from clist_pop can't display in tabular 2nd column

Tags: tables, expl3, latex3

I try to make a clist to table function.
It's work fine in first column, but second column disappear.

Below is MWE (I removed loop part.):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}
    \clist_new:N \l_my_cl
    \clist_set:Nn \l_my_cl {A,B,C,D}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \clist_gpop:NN \l_my_cl \l_tmpa_tl
        \l_tmpa_tl & ``\l_tmpa_tl'' \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

And output :

[image]

Why ??
And how to fix ?
Thanks.

### update

Thanks egreg. This is finally code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}
    \clist_new:N \g_sppmg_my_cl
    \clist_gset:Nn \g_sppmg_my_cl {}

    \int_compare:nNnTF {\clist_count:N \g_sppmg_my_cl} > {0}{
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            \clist_gpop:NN \g_sppmg_my_cl \l_tmpa_tl
            \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl     % copy to global var
            1st. \g_tmpa_tl & ``\g_tmpa_tl'' \\ \hline

            \int_while_do:nNnn {\clist_count:N \g_sppmg_my_cl} > {0} {
                \clist_gpop:NN \g_sppmg_my_cl \l_tmpa_tl
                \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl
                other : \g_tmpa_tl &  ``\g_tmpa_tl'' \\ \hline
            }
        \end{tabular}
    }{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

For `\g_tmpa_tl` in the first column, I think I can use `\g_tmpa_tl` replace `\l_tmpa_tl` in egreg's example.( Actually, it is not necessary in my case.)

Comment: The token list is set in a cell, that forms a group; `gpop` only acts globally on the sequence, but the assignment to the token list variable is local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `\clist_gpop:NN` only acts globally on the clist, but the assignment to the token list variable is local.

Don't mix global and local assignments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}
\clist_new:N \g_sppmg_my_cl
\clist_gset:Nn \g_sppmg_my_cl {A,B,C,D}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\clist_gpop:NN \g_sppmg_my_cl \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl
\l_tmpa_tl & ``\g_tmpa_tl'' \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your answer.(and so fast reply) I use gpop beause used \int_do_while for pop items. I will append full work fine code. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, forget a question, the 1st column work because `\clist_gpop` in the same cell , right ?

Comment: @sppmg Yes, that's right